# Start / Resume Generator without using next

Tags: python

Is there a way to continue a function based on where it was last run.

We want each call to do something else, e.g. (first call adds 1, second adds 2, third call adds 3), and then do something else.

```py
def a_generator():
    yield lambda x: x + 1
    yield lambda x: x + 2
    yield lambda x: x + 3
    yield lambda x: f"Okay we are almost complete {x}"
generator = a_generator()
```

What currently works:

```py
assert next(generator)(5) == 6
assert next(generator)(5) == 7
assert next(generator)(5) == 8
assert next(generator)(5) == "Okay we are almost complete 5"
```

What I want to be able to do:

```py
assert generator(5) == 6
assert generator(5) == 7
assert generator(5) == 8
assert generator(5) == "Okay we are almost complete 5"
```

Comment: How important is StopIteration to you? Can you pass different arguments at each step? A custom class could have whatever state you want and implement iteration or callable.

Comment: The main reason for this question was to be able to patch a function in a test with a stub, that can leave the original code unchanged (i.e. call the function normally), but run different things in each subsequent call (i.e. assert a different statement).

Answer (score 1):

Your code does that already, but consider that you have a generator that returns functions, and treat it accordingly:

```
def a_generator():
    yield lambda x: x + 1
    yield lambda x: x + 2
    yield lambda x: x + 3
    yield lambda x: f"Okay we are almost complete {x}"

for generator in a_generator():
    print(generator(5))
```

> 6
> 7
> 8
> Okay we are almost complete 5

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it seems pretty close so I'll leave it here unless you can narrow down the requirements.

Fundamentally, a generator already is a function that remembers where it was. But you have a generator generating other functions (which are not generators).

Comment: I thought about renaming generator, but I left it alone to match the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me ideas to come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was that I needed to create a generator consumer helper function, and run that instead.

```py
generator = a_generator()

def generator_consumer(x, generator=generator):
    try:
        return next(generator)(x)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("Can't Run the generator anymore")
```

And having the kwarg `generator=generator` means I can just pass args as normal, without needing to specify the generator.

Then I can call the function without calling next.

```py
assert generator_consumer(5) == 6
assert generator_consumer(5) == 7
assert generator_consumer(5) == 8
assert generator_consumer(5) == "Okay we are almost complete 5"
```